# Filter by distance in the same query that calculates it with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am writing a WordPress plugin which is based on code from the plugin [WP_GeoPosts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-geoposts/faq/). This adds a few lines to the query that collects what posts to display for a page, and sorts them by distance to a given latitude/longitude set.

My addition is to filter by distance. The `SELECT` statement returns the calculated distance. I need to compare that distance in the `WHERE` statement.

Below is my SQL which has been formatted for you.

The erroneous line is at the end of the `WHERE` statement, `AND distance <= 25`

```
Error: "Uknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'"
```

**What is the correct way to evaluate the distance, but still return it in the SELECT statement?**

```
SELECT 
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*,
  ( 3959 * acos( 
     cos( radians(44.0519) ) * 
     cos( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) * 
     cos( radians( longitude.meta_value ) - radians(-123.0867) ) + 
     sin( radians(44.0519) ) * 
     sin( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) 
   ) ) AS distance, 
  latitude.meta_value  AS latitude,
  longitude.meta_value AS longitude

FROM wp_posts 
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS latitude ON wp_posts.id = latitude.post_id 
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS longitude ON wp_posts.id = longitude.post_id 

WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'property' 
  AND (
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
  ) 
  AND latitude.meta_key = "latitude" 
  AND longitude.meta_key = "longitude" 
  AND distance <= 25

ORDER BY distance ASC, wp_posts.post_date DESC 

LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "HAVING" after a "WHERE", but just know that "HAVING" can't be optimized the same way has "WHERE".

SELECT 1+bar AS distance FROM foo WHERE something=true HAVING distance < 25;

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: I was not aware of the HAVING keyword, but that seems to work just fine. I'm not sure about the optimization concern at this point, but since this is such a simple calculation I'll go with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline view like so:

```
SELECT CalculatedView.col1, etc... FROM
(
  select
  -- do your main query can calcs in here
) AS CalculatedView
WHERE CalculatedView.SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'
```

Comment: This option might be more WordPress compatible, since WordPress does not have any hooks for a HAVING keyword and I'm not sure of a way to insert my own. So it would have to piggyback off the WHERE hooks, which could in rare cases break other plugins. I'll try to get it to work and see which one works better for my needs. Thanks!